# Issue making a sentence with "to be"

Tags: перевод

> Alice adopted John, when he was 2 years old. At the age of 15 he got to know **who he really is.**

Is is possible to express *to be* in a direct manner without reconstruct these sentences?

Would *Когда ему было 15 лет он узнал **кто он на самом деле есть*** do it?

Comment: Another word order is better: кто он есть на самом деле

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The English verb **to be** in the Present tense can be rendered in Russian in a number of ways, apart from the complete omission of it:

1. `быть (Present есть)` - here two variants are possible,
   a) what follows `есть`, the predicative, is in the Nominative case, that is what you suggested, `он узнал, кто он на самом деле есть`; and b) the predicative is in the Instrumental case, so it is `он узнал, кем он на самом деле есть`;
2. `являться` - it is also followed by the Instrumental case, then your sentence is `он узнал, кем он на самом деле является`. `Являться` is a just a little bit bookish, though.
3. `находиться` - this doesn't fit your sentence at all, it means 'to be [situated]', it is about the place where the subject is, like in `Рейкьявик находится в Исландии.` 'Reykjavík is in Iceland.'

In sentences of the kind `who/what is <somebody/something>?` or `who/what <somebody/something> is` the word `такой, -ая, -ое, -ие` can be added:

> Кто ты такой? - Who are you? (to a man)
>
> Кто ты такая? - Who are you? (to a woman)
>
> Я не знаю, кто они такие. - I don't know who they are.

In this case your sentence will be `он узнал, кто он такой на самом деле`.

Also note that you missed a comma after "узнал."

Comment: to 1. - any difference between using Nominative or Instrumental?

Comment: You have mistakes here. "кем он есть" is ungrammatical, as "есть" does not govern Instrumental. However, it works in past and Future, and also with the verb "являться": "Он узнал, кем он на самом деле был/будет/является". *Является* sounds way too stilted, and I would advise against using it here.

Comment: @shady_arc I've seen hyphens to express *is*. For instance something like `Эта собачка - чудовище`. Can that be used in  any kind of text?

Comment: These — are not hyphens. They are dashes. They are primarily an intonation mark but also are used to connect subject and predicate when predicate is essentially a single noun. Not used in questions, usually is not used with pronouns ("Я чудовище"), normally is not used in negative sentences ("Мой отец не директор"). In all these sentences you MAY insert a dash but it is gonna be purely an intonation mark for emphasis and look weird if you insert it everywhere. Only when connecting a *noun subject* and *noun as a part of nominal predicate* it is obligatory to use dash (in modern punctuation).

Comment: *Являться is a just a little bit bookish, though.* - Okay. Is there any other thing one should consider when choosing between *являться* and *есть / быть*?

Comment: In scientific, historical, linguistic, judiciary, etc. contexts _являться_ is more preferable than _быть_, but remember, _являться_ has another meaning, "to show up, to appear": являться в суд — 'appear before the court'. My dictionary has 35 ways of translating 'to be' into Russian.